# how to make tornado TCPClient use a proxy(http or socks)?

Tags: python, tcp, proxy, tornado

I am searching how to build a proxy pool server , I have asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139697/how-to-write-a-proxy-pool-server-when-a-request-comes-choose-a-proxy-to-get-ur) about that. Because no one could give me a tip, I start to find the way by myself.

Now, I find a good proxy example named `pyproxy` at github which using tornado.I think this line [pyproxy/blob/master/pyproxy.py#L218](https://github.com/binux/pyproxy/blob/master/pyproxy.py#L218) is the key, it uses `tornado.tcpclient.TCPClient().connect(host, int(port)` to connect target site.

`tornado TCPClient` do not take proxy parameter, [doc here](http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tcpclient.html).
I need tornado TCPClient use a http(and socks if possible) proxy to connect target site, then send the result back.
How do I make it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as expected Tornado TCPClient is a... TCP client. Not a HTTP client. So there it's quite logical that you can't use a HTTP proxy with it.

What you could do is talking *TCP* with the remote HTTP proxy. But the you have to implement the proxy protocol yourself.